# How do I Scavenge?

Tags: die2nite

So, in my last town, no one really outlined scavenging all that well to me.  How does autosearch work?  Do I just leave it going, and come back to find items?

What happens if my rucksack is filled and I'm still autosearching?  Do new scavenged items simply get placed on the ground?  Or do I stop finding things?

Is it better if I put down all of my stuff before leaving my character to autosearch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you enter a square for the first time in a day, you have the option to search it. You can do this even if the zone is marked as Depleted, you'll just have less of a chance to find quality items. After you Scavenge the first time, a 2 hour timer will start. After 2 hours, you will search the zone again without having to hit the button or even be online. This is known as **autosearching**.

If your rucksack is filled while you are autosearching, the next time that you come online, the extra items that did not fit into your rucksack will be dropped onto the ground. You *will* keep finding things even if your rucksack fills, you just can't carry them with you.

You can only Scavenge/Autosearch a single square once per day. If you are in square 1/0, decide to scavenge, autosearch for a few hours, then move to 2/0, if you move back to 1/0, you *will not be able to scavenge 1/0 again*. You'll have to wait until the next day.

It's handy to have your rucksack as empty as possible while autosearching, if only because it'll allow you to carry as much as possible back to the town and minimize the amount of AP other people will have to spend coming back to pick up dropped items.

If you become a Hero and choose the Scavenger class, then autosearching will take 30 minutes less and you also have a larger chance to find useful items.

Comment: "...the next time that you come online, the extra items [will be dropped onto the ground]."  Does this mean that WHILE I am autosearching, someone else can't come along and see the dropped items and take some back?  They don't get dropped until I log back in?

Comment: @GnomeSlice: Correct.

Answer (score 4):

Once you click the Scavenge button in a zone, you'll have to wait 2 hours before you can search that zone again. As a convenience, the game will automatically re-search for you whenever possible, even if you're offline.

You will continue to repeatedly search even your if inventory fills up. Items you can't carry will be drop to the ground the next time you log in.

For effective scavenging, set out of town early in the day, find a zone that isn't depleted, and log off for a while. Zones will become depleted after they've been searched so many times, so check back later in the day and move to another one if necessary. When your inventory is full or you're low on AP, haul your loot back to town to earn the admiration and respect of your peers.

Always remember to flag the zone as either depleted or uncleared so people viewing the map will know what to find there.

Comment: What does "uncleared" mean? 'Uncleared of zombies', or 'not depleted' ?

Comment: The icon for "uncleared zone" is a pile of dirt, so I'm assuming it means "not depleted".